# Uncaught TypeError: $(...) is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been working on implementing a JavaScript jQuery script with active nav links and smooth scrolling. It is supposed highlight the nav link when you scroll to a corresponding section (using anchor link) and then also when the user click an navitem it is supposed to highlink that link and scroll to its section. However that only works when, on the index.html page, not cv.html page.

The problem I'm facing is a "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).offset() is undefined", here is a link to the site:

http://jona09h34.web.videndjurs.dk/.

The error can be reproduced when  on CV.html and trying to navigate back to index.html using either of the links (Om mig, Projekter or Kontakt) (translated: About me, Projects, Contact)

EDIT: Rewrote the question, adding a link the site I have problem with.

Comment: open the chrome console and write $ and tap the enter if is not works you need import jquery CDN script

Comment: generally that error points to the execution of `$(...).` code before the jQuery library being loaded completely in to the DOM.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] (emphasis on the *minimal* - the link has advice on how to reduce extraneous stuff from your code). Stackoverflow is supposed to be for solving specific problems, not debugging large piles of code.

Comment: @dılosürücü try this: open a *new tab* in chrome and go to console and enter `$` - that "works" fine.  Browsers define `$` (and `$$`) in the console without jquery.  Check for `$.fn.jquery`.

Comment: *I know this means there is no value of $(...)* - no, it means `$(...).offset() is undefined` - if $() was undefined you would get `$ is not defined`.  Your code does `$("..").offset().top` so it fails when trying to read `.top` of the offset() result.   This happens when your selector doesn't return any elements.  ie `$(target).length === 0`

Comment: Your code relies on `a` elements having a `hash` property,  but you've not included the html for what they refer to, ie there's no `<div id=item1>` so it falls over trying to find the referenced `#item1`.

Comment: After you set `$target`, add: `if ($target.length === 0) { console.error("target missing") ; return; }`   https://jsfiddle.net/kd2ujh6L/

Comment: I just added a bit of clarification, and a link to the website where the problem arises.

Comment: Site works for me with chrome, no errors.

Comment: @grumpy that is weird. I have tested in Firefox, Chrome and Edge with the same outcome.

Comment: @JonasBjørnPedersen Found it, the error only happens when you click on CV and then click on Om mig, thats logical, cv is on a different page cv.html,  and index.html.

Comment: @grumpy yes, but I would like it to be possible to navigate the way you just described with out the errors.

what i don't get is that it is these two lines ```var target = this.hash;
        $target = $(target);``` producing the error. 

The same script is referenced on the two pages, and since using the * operator in $('.navLinks[href*="#"]').on('click', function (e) the should not be a problem with the id's. Since in on html page it is href="#id" and in other it would be href="index.html#id"

Comment: @JonasBjørnPedersen First you have to go back the index.html and then call the the navigate to target, check if location.href is cv or index, set location.href to index, then call the navigate to target.

Comment: @grumpy thank you, that makes sense. Can you give an example with code?

Comment: @JonasBjørnPedersen Question is closed , but someting like if(window.location.href =="http://jona09h34.web.videndjurs.dk/cv.html"){location.href="http://jona09h34.web.videndjurs.dk/index.html"), then do the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your immediate problem:**

First of all - check the destination URL in the bottom left of your browser when you hover over the navigation links on the CV page. Notice how they point to to the cv page with the # appended, but all your content is on your index page.

Your `activeLink.js` file is listening for clicks on those nav elements and then using the `hash` value to find the top of a matching `<div>` and scroll to it. But those target divs only exist on your homepage, not your CV page.

You have a couple of options to fix it. The quickest way would be to modify your javascript to check the current `window.location` and only fire your "smooth scrolling" code if it's on the homepage.

**Fixing it a different way:**

You could go a step further and remove *all* the javascript that handles page scrolling (lines 10-48 in your `activeLink.js`) and let CSS do it. You could add the following to your css:

```css
html {
  scroll-behaviour:smooth;
  scroll-padding-top: 100px; 
}
```

`scroll-padding-top` lets you specify an offset to account for your fixed header. You'll need to modify that value and probably add a media query so it works for your smaller mobile header too.

Now, you need change your navigation links so they still work regardless of the page you are on. Rather than just `<a href="#about">Om mig</a>`, add the full path: `<a href="index.html#about">Om mig</a>`. Now if you click the link when you're *not* on index.html, you'll load the correct page. The smooth scrolling will kick in and you'll be taken to the correct anchor.

Comment: The first solution works, thank you. 

However due to a fixed header, which the smothscrolling handles, when navigating from the cv.html page, that dosen't work since it is the code producing the error.

Do you have any idea, how to make that work, without using the HTML solution?

Comment: You already wrap your code in `document.ready`, so you could just test the `window.location.hash` has a value when the page loads and if so apply your custom scroll handler. I wouldn't necessarily recommend that though, it's not great for accessibility. There's a good article on this here: https://css-tricks.com/smooth-scrolling-accessibility/

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to work for me but try changing your browser or script tag. I'd recommend this one:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I will try changing browser and cdn link. Thank you.

EDIT: tried using Chrome and the other CDN link, but it did nothing.